# How write test cases for custom actions in Botframework composer using Node JS

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I want to know how can I write test cases for custom actions dialogs, can you provide some samples so that I can get an idea, Many Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? I don't have experience with writing test cases for composer, but I think the dialogs should be defined very similar to doing it in code. Have you tried using the Bot Framework Test adapter and setting up a test conversation flow?

Comment: @billoverton I want to test my custom actions before integrating it with botframework composer